# How to get name property from array of objects arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have array, which contains arrays of objects from different tables. How can I get all names of all these objects in array of arrays?
I know, they are weirdly nested, but that's how structure is for now.
[image]

Comment: Recursive (if needed) loop!

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```js
const getNames = (data) => data.flat().map(({name})=> name)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a nested for loop on the array

```
var names = []
for (let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    for(let j = 0 ; j<array[i].length; j ++){
        names.push(array[i][j].name)
    }
}
console.log(names)
```